# asp.net stored procedure problem

Tags: asp.net

Why this code don't work,when i want run this code vwd 2008 express show me this error message:Invalid object name 'answers'.

this is my ascx.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
public partial class odgl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string connectionString =
  @"SANATIZEDSTRING!!!!";


        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {


    using (SqlCommand dohvati = new SqlCommand("dbo.get_answers",cn)) {


        dohvati.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter izracun = new SqlParameter("@count", SqlDbType.Int);
        izracun.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        dohvati.Parameters.Add(izracun);

        cn.Open();


        dohvati.ExecuteNonQuery();
        int count = Int32.Parse(dohvati.Parameters["@count"].Value.ToString());

        Response.Write(count.ToString());


        cn.Close();

    }

}

    }
}
```

and this is my stored procedure 
:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[get_answers]
@ukupno int output


as
select @count= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM answers)
go
```

Comment: For future reference, never include your SQL Server Connection string in your code that you put on a web site for all the world to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you don't have an `answers` table in your `dbo` schema of the `estudent_pioo` database on the `xxxxx\PADME` server.

And the stored procedure you posted is would not even run. Perhaps you meant:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[get_answers]
  @count int output

as
  select @count= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM answers)
go
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to exist in your procedure... Are you sure that Answer table exist and belongs to dbo schema?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've specified the correct DB to connect to in the connection string

Answer (score 0):

Is 'answers' a table or view in the same DB as your stored procedure?
Try running the stored procedure directly from SQL.

Looks like you are also going to have problems with the parameter. Should be @count?